# Is it possible to add google map or Esri map in viewer of Autodesk forge for 3d Model?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to load Base Map in Autodesk viewer for 3d RVT model. I know, It is not possible as per documentation provided by forge site but I would like to know if anyone found any workaround.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as reference: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/GoogleMapsLocator

Comment: hi varunpatil, i did try that extension but i got the the following message when open map "this page can't load Google Maps correctly.", after click OK then map has water mark say "For development purpose only", did i miss something?

Comment: console error message -> You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable

Comment: Please go through details on the google maps product, we may not be able to help regarding google maps pricing and rules.